# Do the real numbers and an inner product form a Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras

I am just starting learn about Lie algebras and I saw it defined that a Lie algebra is a vector space with a commutator operation that is 1) bilinear, 2) satisfies the Jacobi identity, 3) [x,x]=0. Over a one dimensional real inner-product space, is it the possible to form a Lie algebra by defining the commutator operation to be the inner product? Thanks.

Comment: No, because the values of the Lie operation on a vector space $V$ lie in $V$, not in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Ah, okay that makes sense, but in the one dimensional case, since $V=\mathbb{R}$, how does one distinguish between the field and the vector space (after all, as sets, they are identical)?

Comment: Even in the case that $V= \Bbb R$ (on which any inner product is just a scalar multiple of ordinary multiplication), is it the case that $x^2=0$ for all $x$? Or that $3xyz=0$ for all $x,y,z \in \Bbb R$?

Answer (score 3):

No. You can show that for one dimension real inner product vector spaces, that is, $\mathbb{R}$, that $\langle x, x\rangle = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$. You can see how this is going to be a problem for axiom 3 when we ask that $\langle 1, 1 \rangle = 0$.

Comment: Oh right! That clarifies this a lot. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Well, antisimmetry is quite an obvious obstacle...